# How to use Django list as a javascript variable in Django template?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, google-visualization

I have a Django list by named `list_a`:

```
[['Host Name', 'No. of Events'], [u'12.23.21.23', 0], [u'2.152.0.2', 2]]
```

I am using `Google Chart API` in my Django template. I have to paas `list_a` to the following java script variable:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Host_name', 'No of events'], 
    ['12.23.21.23', 0], 
    ['2.152.0.2', 2]
    ]);
```

The above one is hard coded, but i want to use in the following way:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{list_a}});
```

I tried with the above code and checked with the `javascript console` option provided in chrome. It show this:

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([[&#39;Host Name&#39;, &#39;No. of Events&#39;], [u&#39;12.23.21.23&#39;, 0], [u&#39;2.152.0.2&#39;, 2]]);
```

I compared with this above line with the hard coded code, It is very different because of following way:

```
&#39;
['12.23.21.23', 0]  See the quotes on ip address field but not to the next field
```

How should i make the `list_a` equivalent to the hard coded, So that i can easily get the required chart.

Apart from that why this `&#39` is occurring when i tried to use it directly

I am using this https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart sample of Google charts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encode it as JSON, mark it safe, and print it out.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{ list_a|json|safe }})
```

Unfortunately you'll need to write or find the `json` filter, or encode it as JSON in the view.

Comment: @Hamish: A "u" in front of a string is not valid JavaScript.